# Graceful shutdown while actor is waiting for a reply

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have an Akka cluster with 2 nodes and deploy using a rolling update strategy.

`Actor A` sends a message to `Actor B` and becomes a behaviour which waits for a reply.

Example `Actor A` implementation:

```
class ActorA extends AbstractActor {
    private ActorRef sender;

    static Props props () {
        return Props.create(ActorA.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return ReceiveBuilder.create()
                .matchAny(msg -> {
                    sender = getSender();
                    getContext().become(waiting());
                })
                .build();
    }

    private Receive waiting() {
        return ReceiveBuilder.create()
                .matchAny(msg -> sender.tell("COMPLETE", getSelf()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

A deployment happens at the same time, so the node containing `Actor A` receives a `SIGTERM` and starts a graceful shutdown. From what I've understood from the Akka docs, a graceful shutdown involves sending a `PoisonPill` to all actors on the node.

So what happens to `Actor A`? It was waiting for a response from `Actor B` but has now received a `PoisonPill`. What happens when `Actor B` replies to its sender?

In my case `Actor A` will never receive the response.

Comment: What would you expect here? In any case, message delivery is at-least-once in Akka, so you cannot rely on all messages being delivered anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make a complete answer out of /u/jrudolph 's comment, Actor A will not get a response. Which it needs to be prepared to deal with anyway, since message delivery is "at-most-once". There are lots of potential reasons that Actor B might not send a response, graceful shutdown being a relatively obscure reason.

Any actor that requires a response has to have some mechanism to deal with situations where it doesn't get that response. That can be a simple retry, Akka's built in guaranteed message delivery (where it will automatically retry), or any method.